# React componentDidMount "Parsing error: Missing semicolon"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**"Parsing error: Missing semicolon"**.

> SyntaxError: client\src\App.js: Missing semicolon (15:21)

This error is showing on componentDidMount() line.

and the full code is given below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AppNavBar from "./components/AppNavbar";
import ShoppingList from "./components/ShoppingList";
import ItemModal from "./components/ItemModal";
import { Container } from "reactstrap";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
import { loadUser } from "./actions/authActions";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className="App">
        <AppNavBar />
        <Container>
          <ItemModal />
          <ShoppingList />
        </Container>
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Error ScreenShot]

Comment: `componentDidMount` is used in class based React, you appear to be using Hooks, you can't mix them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import useEffect:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
```

... and replace:

```
componentDidMount() {
  store.dispatch(loadUser());
}
```

with:

```
useEffect(() => {
  store.dispatch(loadUser());
}, []);
```

Comment: useEffect is called for state update and also initial render. So in some cases it is not wise to use useEffect. componentDidMount is called after the state is updated only.

Comment: i want to call only once time first init only, did useEffect working?

Comment: @famfamfam `useEffect` with empty dependency list works once immediately upon the first render